# How to scatter plot a dict of lists containing arrays in Matplotlib? (Screenshot in details)

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, plot, k-means

What I want to do is plotting data in a *dict*, preferably using Matplotlib.
Below is a screenshot since I think looking at the data structure makes it easier to understand. But here is also a description.

- A *dict* contains 7 *lists*.
- Each *list* represents a cluster.
- Each *list* contains a number of *arrays* with two items in it.
- Each *array* represents a two-dimensional point.

I want to recreate the results in this Blog post. Unfortunately the author didn't provide the code he used for the plots. 
https://datasciencelab.wordpress.com/2013/12/12/clustering-with-k-means-in-python/

Here is the screenshot:

[image]

In case it helps, here is the full code I used to generate the clusters:

```
import numpy as np
import random
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt # STACKOVERFLOW

# k-Means Algorithm (Lloyd's Algorithm) 
def cluster_points(X, mu):
    clusters  = {}
    for x in X:
        bestmukey = min([(i[0], np.linalg.norm(x-mu[i[0]])) \
                    for i in enumerate(mu)], key=lambda t:t[1])[0]
        try:
            clusters[bestmukey].append(x)
        except KeyError:
            clusters[bestmukey] = [x]
    return clusters

def reevaluate_centers(mu, clusters):
    newmu = []
    keys = sorted(clusters.keys())
    for k in keys:
        newmu.append(np.mean(clusters[k], axis = 0))
    return newmu

def has_converged(mu, oldmu):
    return set([tuple(a) for a in mu]) == set([tuple(a) for a in oldmu])

def find_centers(X, K):
    # Initialize to K random centers
    oldmu = random.sample(X, K)
    mu = random.sample(X, K)
    while not has_converged(mu, oldmu):
        oldmu = mu
        # Assign all points in X to clusters
        clusters = cluster_points(X, mu)
        # Reevaluate centers
        mu = reevaluate_centers(oldmu, clusters)
    return(mu, clusters)


# initialization
def init_board_gauss(N, k):
    n = float(N)/k
    X = []
    for i in range(k):
        c = (random.uniform(-1, 1), random.uniform(-1, 1))
        s = random.uniform(0.05,0.5)
        x = []
        while len(x) < n:
            a, b = np.array([np.random.normal(c[0], s), np.random.normal(c[1], s)])
            # Continue drawing points from the distribution in the range [-1,1]
            if abs(a) < 1 and abs(b) < 1:
                x.append([a,b])
        X.extend(x)
    X = np.array(X)[:N]
    return X

X = init_board_gauss(200,3)

# generating clusters
mu, clusters = find_centers(X, 7)
clusters = cluster_points(X, mu)
```

Comment: And what have you tried? Matplotlib as a lot of documentation and examples available. Have you read any of it?

Comment: This might be a philosophical problem but let me try to convince you. Please don't just tell people to RTFM. In case the problem can be obviously answered by looking at the manual, link to the relevant part of it and people will be glad to read it. In case it can't be obviously answered by looking at the manual, the question might be worth being asked and deserves a proper answer. In my case there was nothing about iterating over a dict in the manual and there could be a better solution someone else knows about. Thanks for wanting to push me into what you considered the right direction though.

Comment: You just proved my point: with a bit of effort you found the answer yourself. People will generally be happy to help you, if they first see some honest attempts from your part to solve your own question. As it was posted, your question was like "please write code for me" with no signs that you may have read the doco, or with specific question that is not answered in the doco. Such questions will usually attract similar answers to mine. Thanks for sharing your solution though! For your next questions you may want to read this first http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came up with a solution. [image]

Here is what I changed/added to the code:

```
# Initialize points
n_points = 200
n_clusters = 7
X = init_board_gauss(n_points, n_clusters)

# Cluster points
mu, clusters = find_centers(X, n_clusters)
clusters = cluster_points(X, mu)

# Generate random colors
def generate_random_color():
    r = lambda: random.randint(0,255)
    return '#%02X%02X%02X' % (r(),r(),r())

# Plot each cluster
for i in range(0, n_clusters):
    colx = tuple(x[0] for x in clusters[i])
    coly = tuple(x[1] for x in clusters[i])
    cluster_color = generate_random_color()
    plt.scatter(colx,coly, color=cluster_color)
```

And here is the full code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import random

# k-Means Algorithm (Lloyd's Algorithm) 
def cluster_points(X, mu):
    clusters  = {}
    for x in X:
        bestmukey = min([(i[0], np.linalg.norm(x-mu[i[0]])) \
                    for i in enumerate(mu)], key=lambda t:t[1])[0]
        try:
            clusters[bestmukey].append(x)
        except KeyError:
            clusters[bestmukey] = [x]
    return clusters

def reevaluate_centers(mu, clusters):
    newmu = []
    keys = sorted(clusters.keys())
    for k in keys:
        newmu.append(np.mean(clusters[k], axis = 0))
    return newmu

def has_converged(mu, oldmu):
    return set([tuple(a) for a in mu]) == set([tuple(a) for a in oldmu])

def find_centers(X, K):
    # Initialize to K random centers
    oldmu = random.sample(X, K)
    mu = random.sample(X, K)
    while not has_converged(mu, oldmu):
        oldmu = mu
        # Assign all points in X to clusters
        clusters = cluster_points(X, mu)
        # Reevaluate centers
        mu = reevaluate_centers(oldmu, clusters)
    return(mu, clusters)


# Initialization
def init_board(N):
    X = np.array([(random.uniform(-1, 1), random.uniform(-1, 1)) for i in range(N)])
    return X    

def init_board_gauss(N, k):
    n = float(N)/k
    X = []
    for i in range(k):
        c = (random.uniform(-1, 1), random.uniform(-1, 1))
        s = random.uniform(0.05,0.5)
        x = []
        while len(x) < n:
            a, b = np.array([np.random.normal(c[0], s), np.random.normal(c[1], s)])
            # Continue drawing points from the distribution in the range [-1,1]
            if abs(a) < 1 and abs(b) < 1:
                x.append([a,b])
        X.extend(x)
    X = np.array(X)[:N]
    return X


# Initialize points
n_points = 200
n_clusters = 7
X = init_board_gauss(n_points, n_clusters)

# Cluster points
mu, clusters = find_centers(X, n_clusters)
clusters = cluster_points(X, mu)

# Generate random colors
def generate_random_color():
    r = lambda: random.randint(0,255)
    return '#%02X%02X%02X' % (r(),r(),r())

# Plot each cluster
for i in range(0, n_clusters):
    colx = tuple(x[0] for x in clusters[i])
    coly = tuple(x[1] for x in clusters[i])
    cluster_color = generate_random_color()
    plt.scatter(colx,coly, color=cluster_color)
```